# How to install YaxGUI to work with tideways in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, user-interface, xhprof, code-profiling

I've just installed [tideways](https://github.com/tideways/php-profiler-extension) (fork from xhprof), and found this GUI [YaxGUI](https://github.com/sfeni/yaxgui), the installation steps wasn't clear enough for me.

> Install your favourite mix of PHP and web server
>   Install MySQL server
>   Clone the project to some folder
>   Map the sub folder xhprof_html to be accessible over HTTP
>   Move xhprof_lib/config.sample.php to xhprof_lib/config.php
>   Edit xhprof_lib/config.php
>   Update the SQL server configuration
>   Update the URL of the service (should point to xhprof_html over HTTP)
>   Update the dot_binary configuration - otherwise no call graphs!
>   Update the controlIPs variable to enable access.
>   For a development machine you can set this to false to disable IP checks.
>   Import the DB schema (it is just 1 table)
>   See the SQL at xhprof_runs.php
>   Add a PHP configuration to enable the profiling
>   If using Apache you can edit your virtual host configuration
>   Add php_admin_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/xhprof/external/header.php"
>   Visit http://your-server/xhprof/xhprof_html/ and be amazed!
>   To get profiler information showing up there visit your page with a GET variable _profile=1.
>   For example http://localhost/?_profile=1

I stopped at this point:

> Import the DB schema (it is just 1 table)

And don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

On the yaxgui project folder you find a folder named utils inside this folder there should be a folder named Db.

Inside the Db folder you will find various database drivers, so you can choose the database connection type you will use (ie: the PDO Driver),choose your driver and open the php file inside it you will find the sql to create the necessary tables to use PDO you need to run this on your database to create the necessary table.

( you find this code in the top of the file Pdo.php )

```
CREATE TABLE `details` (
     `id` char(17) NOT NULL,
     `url` varchar(255) default NULL,
     `c_url` varchar(255) default NULL,
     `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `server name` varchar(64) default NULL,
     `perfdata` MEDIUMBLOB,
     `type` tinyint(4) default NULL,
     `cookie` BLOB,
     `post` BLOB,
     `get` BLOB,
     `pmu` int(11) unsigned default NULL,
     `wt` int(11) unsigned default NULL,
     `cpu` int(11) unsigned default NULL,
     `server_id` char(3) NOT NULL default 't11',
     `aggregateCalls_include` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
     KEY `url` (`url`),
     KEY `c_url` (`c_url`),
     KEY `cpu` (`cpu`),
     KEY `wt` (`wt`),
     KEY `pmu` (`pmu`),
     KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

don't forget to properly edit the xhprof_lib/config.php file with the correct database user and password.

Comment: Actually, at that time I've created the database and  then stopped, for any beginner like me the next step is to add the header.php file to php.ini, for some reason (I don't know why ) it will not work also, someone adviced me to run the folder on deferent port (port 3000) and it worked well.

Comment: at that point I create a .ini file for php
"
extension=tideways.so
tideways.auto_prepend_library=0
auto_prepend_file=<full_path_to_header.php>
"
if you don't use "tideways.auto_prepend_library=0" it gives a kind of cryptic error "You do not have permission to view this page."